# Name the nested Object from Json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to add and name a nested object in my `Json`
My `Json` looks like that:

```
 {
        "MH": [
            {
                "MHF46": "Ledig",
                "MHF60": "60",      
            },    
        ]
    }
```

I want to add a nested object so it will looks like that:

```
{
    "MH": [
        {
            "MHF46": "Ledig",
            "MHF60": "60",      
        },
         "QMSI" : [
            {}
        ]    
    ]
}
```

This is what i have tried but this will give me not the `Json` back that i want

```
MH = [
          MH[0].SurveyResults[0].result,
          [(MH[0].SurveyResults[0].QMSI)]
        ];
```

this is the `Json` i get with this code:

```
{
    "MH": [
        {
            "MHF46": "Ledig",
            "MHF60": "60",
        },
        [
            "QMSI"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: what you want to do is not possible, because you expect an array item to be a key value pair.

Comment: It should be 'MH[0][" QMSI"] = [{}];'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not valid JavaScript/JSON. `"MH"` can either be a List (`"MH": [a, b]`) or an Object (`"MH": {"key1": a, "key2": b}`), not both (an array with a named key `"MH": [a, "key2": b]`). You might be able to create some crazy edge cases with an Object that resembles a List by having only numbers as keys (`"MH": {0: a, "key2": b}`), but I'd really refrain from that.

Instead, give your data model another thought and overthink if `"MH"` should be a List (then you'd get e.g. `"MH": [{"MHF46": "Ledig, "MHF60": "60"}, {"QMSI": [{}]}]`) or an Object (then you'd get e.g. `"MH": {"MHF46": "Ledig", "MHF60": "60", QMSI: [{}]}`).

Comment: It is possible in javascript.

Comment: you are totally right. i was thinking too fast and too wrong. With your answer i found a solution. <3

Answer (score 1):

This JSON is not valid because an array is not an object and can't have a field.

Solution 1: You'll have to put `QMSI` in an object

```
{
    "MH": [
        {
            "MHF46": "Ledig",
            "MHF60": "60",      
        },
        {
            "QMSI" : [
                {}
            ]    
        }
    ]
}
```

Solution 2: Change the `MH` type to object instead of array

```
{
    "MH": {
        "MHF46": "Ledig",
        "MHF60": "60",      
        "QMSI" : [
            {}
        ]    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be setting the property into an array, but just to clear **`It is Possible in javascript`**

```js
let obj = {
  "MH": [
   {
  "MHF46": "Ledig",
  "MHF60": "60",
 },
  ]
}

obj.MH.QMSI = [{}]    

console.log(obj.MH.QMSI)
```

Also these properties will not be enumerable so not recommended as already mentioned in other answers.